# Gradle error : Could not find method maybeCreate() for arguments [victims] on configuration container

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am getting error while configuring victims plugin in build.gradle. Gradle version is 2.0.

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo url: "http://xxxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/content/groups/public/"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.xxxx.xxx.crm:gradle-plugins:1.3.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'victims'

victims {
    fingerprint = 'fatal'
    updates = 'auto'
}
```

Error is :

> Could not find method maybeCreate() for arguments [victims] on configuration container.

Same configuration works in my another project without that method(maybeCreate()) declaration. But I am not sure, what I am missing here? 
Can someone advise me?

Comment: same plugin version in the other project?  can you run with --debug and output the error?

Comment: @Al Jacinto : Thanks for your quick reply.yes same plugin version in both the projects. I can't attach the error log as its more than 500 characters length.

Comment: Any insight on that maybeCreate error?  Do you have that anywhere?  victims is your task.  Do you have that method somewhere for that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. 
The issue was with the old gradle version. I have changed the gradle version from 1.3 to 1.10 in distributionUrl property in gradle-wrapper.properties solves the issue.

```
distributionUrl=http://xxxx.xxx.xom/gradle/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
```

Anyway thanks for your help Al Jacinto.